# passport odd behavior in auth

Tags: node.js, passport.js, ejs

I coded a simple blog with node.js and used passport for auth and ejs for view engine
when i login some navbar link change as expected but odd thing is when i login from normal chrome tab, and refresh site from another chrome incognito window or even another browser for example edge, I see Logged in version of navbar and i did not login from edge or incognito in chrome
here are my code

html

```
 <% if (!logedIn) { %>
 <li><a href="/login" class="navlink">Login</a></li>
 <li><a href="/register" class="navlink">Register</a></li>
 <% } else { %>
 <li><a href="/compose" class="navlink">New!</a></li>
 <li><a href="/logout" class="navlink">LogOut</a></li>
 <li><a href="/chat" class="navlink">ChatRoom</a></li>
 <% } %>
```

server

```
app.get('/',function(req,res) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        logedIn = true;
    }
    Post.find(function(err,posts) {
        if(err){
           console.log(err);;
        } else {
            res.render('home',{posts:posts,logedIn:logedIn})
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Offtopic, but I would suggest creating a middleware for the `req.isAuthenticated()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is using a global variable `logedIn`, so if one user is logged in, it treats all other users as logged in as well.

To fix this, simply make `logedIn` a local variable:

```js
app.get('/',function(req,res) {
    // define variables using keywords like var, let, const, etc. Omitting them may create unwanted global variables.
    let logedIn = false;
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        logedIn = true;
    }
    Post.find(function(err,posts) {
        if(err){
           console.log(err);;
        } else {
            res.render('home',{posts:posts,logedIn:logedIn})
        }
    })
})
```